# Salt and jinja variables

Tags: jinja2, salt-stack

I want use variable as parameter in my state:

I have value in map.jinja:

```
'package_9.6': '3.7.5-1',
```

I declared variable in my state:

```
{% set package_version = '9.6' %}
```

Then I added string to it:

```
{% set something = "my_package.package_" ~ package_version %}
```

And want to use all this in my state

```
{% from "somewhere/map.jinja" import my_package with context %}
      pkg.installed:
        - pkgs:
          - my_package: {{ something }}
```

In perfect universe I would like to resolve value of my variable to value from map.jinja (3.7.5-1). But I am getting **my_package.package_9.6** string.

Maybe it is totally wrong way of meeting my needs, but after some experiments I got to this option.

Answer (score 1):

You need to import `map.jinja` file in your state file to make use of the variable before using them.

```
{% from "path-to-map" import map with context %}
```

In your `map.jinja` file, variable should be declared as

```
{% set package_9.6 = '3.7.5-1' %}
```

You can then access it in a state file using,

```
{% set something = "my_package.package_" ~ map.package_9.6 %}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I did.
I am getting error  `E: Version 'my_package.package_9.6' for 'my_package' was not found` . if I had no access to map.jinja I would get something like 
_Jinja variable 'dict object' has no attribute ..._

Comment: you need to esape . as well 9\.6